# Limit of a product $(x+2)(k^x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a quick question regarding limits of a function

How do I show that the limit of $f(x)$ tends to 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$ where

$$f(x) = (x+2)(k^x) $$
where $0<k<1$.

Can I say that the limit of the left product converges to $\infty$ but the second limit converges to $0$ and so the whole limit converges to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say that, for example, if I have $f(x) = (x^2) \cdot \frac1x$, then the left product converges to $\infty$ and the second converges to $0$, but the whole limit is $\infty$.

My advice here is to use L'Hospital's rules, as $$f(x) = \frac{x+2}{\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^x}.$$ Both functions, $x+2$ and $\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^x$, have a limit of $\infty$, so the use of L'Hospital is justifies.

Comment: can i simply say that since the linear approaches to $\infty$ slower than the power function, and since $\frac 1 k >1$ so the whole fraction converges to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Comment: You have to *prove* that the linear approaches $\infty$ slower than the power function. However, this is equivalent to showing that the limit of $\frac{x}{\alpha^x}$ is $0$ for $\alpha>1$. So no, you cannot just "say" what you want, since that is exactly what you must prove.

Comment: CAN! I got it. Use L'Hospital, take derivative of both. Numerator becomes 1 while denominator is $\alpha ^x \log \alpha$. Take the denominator limit to $\infty$, denominator $\rightarrow \infty$, whole fraction $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Well done. There exist more elementary proofs of the statement, however I believe this is the simplest one. As always, if the answer is what you were looking for, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you rewrite the second term:

$$k^x = e^{x\cdot\ln{k}}$$

Then: $X = x\cdot\ln{k}$. 
When $x \rightarrow \infty$, $X \rightarrow -\infty$ ($\ln(k)$ is negative). You can rewrite the whole by also developing: $$f(x) = \frac{X}{\ln{k}} \cdot e^{X} + 2 \cdot e^{X}$$

The second term clearly converges to $0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$ as $X \rightarrow -\infty$. And the first term also converges to $0$ because $x \cdot e^{-x} \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

*Proof of the last assumption:*

For $x > 2 \cdot \ln{2}$ we have $x < e^{x/2}$. You can derive $g(x) = x - e^{x/2}$ to convince yourself. It means that for $x > 2 \cdot \ln{2}$:

$$0<x \cdot e^{-x} < e^{x/2} e^{-x} = e^{x/2 - x} = e^{-x/2}$$

And the term in the right converges to $0$, so by comparison you have the result.

Comment: "And the first term also converges to 0 because $x \cdot e^{x} \rightarrow 0$ when $x \rightarrow -\infty$"

You say that like it is a self evident truth. This is a statement that needs to be proven. It's proof is just as difficult as the original statement. Therefore, this is a bad answer.

Comment: I assume this is a known result if the requirements are as high as L'Hospital rule. But fine, I will prove it.

Comment: The thing is that if it is a known result, then any proof that proves it also proves OP's question, so I don't think it's OK to presuppose it.

Comment: I edited it, now the proof is complete unless I have to prove that the last term converges to 0 when $x \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: $k$ is not negative

Comment: indeed, typo from me. k is not negative, but ln(k) is.

Comment: I've tried to make it a bit more readable. For instance, important formulas should be highlighted with double dollar signs, and a fraction in the exponent ($e^{\frac{x}{2}}$) is not very readable; I only see a smudge on my screen where there is supposed to be an $x$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I knew my formatting was terrible (I'm only beginning to use SO) !